# Python 2.7: Get all unique values from a list, removing any value that is or has been repeated

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

What is a reasonable way to get only the unique values from a list in Python 2.7? For example, if a value is repeated, delete the repeat AND the original value from the list. Thus, we are left with only the values that have never been repeated.

Intuitively, I would create a `set` from the list, and a `bag` (ie `multiset`) from the `list`, and take the values from the `list` that are NOT in the `bag` MINUS `set` collection. However, I cannot find an easy implementation for `bag` (or `multiset`) in Python 2.7. Any suggestions? It would be nice to implement this using only set and bag operations.

**Example**
Here a my best implementation, using a brute force approach:

This example uses a list of friends, where if a friend is listed more than once, they are no longer a friend:

```
list_of_friends = ['bill','bill','mark','jenna','brad','mark']
unique_list_of_friends = []
for friend in list_of_friends:
    if (friend in list_of_friends):
        list_of_friends.remove(friend)
        if (friend not in list_of_friends):
            unique_list_of_friends.append(friend)
        # Ensure that all duplicates of current friend are removed
        list_of_friends = [f for f in list_of_friends if f != friend]
```

Finally, we are left with:

```
unique_list_of_friends = ['jenna','brad']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of matches the method you describe using set/bag

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list_of_friends = ['bill','bill','mark','jenna','brad','mark']
>>> S = set(list_of_friends)
>>> bag = Counter(list_of_friends)
>>> S.difference(bag - Counter(S))
set(['brad', 'jenna'])
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list_of_friends = ['bill','bill','mark','jenna','brad','mark']
>>> [k for k, v in Counter(list_of_friends).items() if v == 1]
['brad', 'jenna']
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(['bill','bill','mark','jenna','brad','mark'])
>>> [k for k in c.keys() if c[k] == 1]
['brad', 'jenna']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list_of_friends = ['bill','bill','mark','jenna','brad','mark']
unique_list_of_friends = [i for i in list_of_friends if list_of_friends.count(i) == 1]
print(unique_list_of_friends)
```

Comment: This does work, however the use of `count()` makes it `O(n^2)`. Using `Counter()` gives an `O(n)` solution

Comment: @ginbbler: Yeah, you are right, Counter() is a better choice than this, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if for some reason you can't use a `Counter` (ugh why?)

```
list_of_friends = ['bill','bill','mark','jenna','brad','mark']
a_set = set()
b_set = set()
for friend in list_of_friends:
    if friend not in a_set:
        a_set.add(friend)
    else:
        b_set.add(friend)
result = a_set - b_set
```

Comment: Note that I strongly recommend the use of `collections.Counter` for this. It's a canonical use of it to be sure. However since you explicitly asked for `set` functions only....

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use recursion:

```
In [83]: def retUn(x):
   ....:     if not x: return []
   ....:     if x[0] in x[1:]: return retUn( filter(lambda m: m != x[0], x) )
   ....:     else: return [ x[0] ] + retUn( x[1:] )
   ....:

In [84]: retUn(x)
Out[84]: ['jenna', 'brad']
```

Comment: I feel like this should be far slower than set operations. For large lists, certainly, since you're building `2n-1` lists, using `O(n!)` to compare, and filtering `n` lists. Not awful, but could be improved!

Answer (score 0):

This is hideous and far too clever but it works:

```
list_of_friends = ['bill', 'bill', 'mark', 'jenna', 'brad', 'mark']
set_of_friends = set(list_of_friends)
[list_of_friends.remove(friend) for friend in set_of_friends]

real_friends = [friend for friend in set_of_friends if friend not in list_of_friends]
print(real_friends) # ['brad', 'jenna']
```

Comment: unroll that list comp into a `for` loop. Don't use list comprehensions for their side effects.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yeah I'm aware that's the proper way. I honestly find this significantly more readable and wish it was usable syntax without the innate comprehension (and brackets).

Comment: It's FAR less readable to me. I kept trying to figure out what you did with that list ("why build it if he doesn't use it") and looking for a `NameError` in your final list comp as if you neglected to name it. Then I realized that you were using `list.remove` which returns `None`, and thought "Oh, silly Chris thinks he's using `list.pop` and only two minutes later realized you were really just using a one-liner for loop

Comment: Always code for the guy that comes after you. You'll REMEMBER what your code does. The poor sap who has to maintain your code after you're off the project will hate your guts if you violate PEP8 like this :)

Comment: Yeah, the brackets make it nasty and admittedly confusing. If I give it parenthesis instead and create a generator, is there a good way to 'execute' that generator? Definitely theoretical territory here, but I mentally prefer the 'action on x for each x in collection' to 'for each x ...' in terms of English readability.

Comment: @ChrisArena, since all the terms are `None`, you can use `any(...)` but don't do it in real code please :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the potpourri of answers, here's one using `itertools.groupby()`. This is kind of the same as the `Counter` m\ethod, but probably less efficient.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list_of_friends = ['bill','bill','mark','jenna','brad','mark']
>>> [k for k,v in itertools.groupby(sorted(list_of_friends)) if len(list(v)) == 1]
['brad', 'jenna']
```

Answer (score 0):

A good old list comprehension with a filter inside should do the trick:

```
>>> a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3]
>>> b = [i for i in a if len(filter(lambda x,val=i: x == val, a)) == 1]
>>> b
[2, 5]
```

Be careful as it does not mutate the initial list but construct a new list.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,5,4,3,2,1,1,12,4,6,2,3,7,9,4,1]
b = []
print(a)
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if(a[i] == b[j]):
            count = count + 1

    if(count == 0):
        b.append(a[i])
    count = 0
print(b)
```

output:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 12, 4, 6, 2, 3, 7, 9, 4, 1]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 7, 9]